# How to generate a file with Node.js from a predefined template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am building an app with React Native and when I need a new component, I go through a few steps (lets assume I need a Button component) :

1. Create a new folder: `/src/components/Button`
2. Create `Button.js`
3. Create `Button.styles.js`
4. Create `index.js`, which exports both the component and its styles

That's takes some time, so I want to create a script that does the following things:

1. Prompts a new component name
2. Checks if that component already exists. If so, displays error
3. Creates files listed above with predefined templates, for example:

   ```
   import $component from './$component';
   import styles from './$component.styles';

   export { $component, styles };
   ```

   where `$component` is a name, provided via cli.

I can create folder and files with node, but how can I write a template and provide a variable to those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template file manually. While running your script, read the contents of the file and then replace predetermined variable *($component for example)* with the name from the console.